# how to debug i/o buffering of my c application?

Tags: c, io, buffer

I'm reading through the book Advanced Programming for the Unix Environment, and working my way through the i/o buffering section.

To help my understanding of buffering, it would be useful if I could debug and monitor the buffer in my simple c application to get a better understanding of how the buffering has been implemented.  My simple c application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("c:\\Users\\snowc\\Desktop\\myc.txopen", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

In a java environment, I can attach the i/o library source code to my debugging session and then step through the i/o library code.  Is it possible to do something similar in c, so that I can see what happens when I call `fprintf()` or some other i/o method?

Using eclipse CDT, I can navigate to the `fprintf()` function call from my code, but it just takes me to what appears to be a macro definition in stdio.h:

```
int _EXFUN(fprintf, (FILE *, const char *, ...)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step through it in gdb, the [GNU Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/):

```
$ gdb ./yourprogram
(gdb) break main.c:6
Breakpoint set at main.c line 6
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1 hit
(gdb) step
```

Alternatively, run it in strace:

```
strace ./yourprogram
```